# cordova generate signed apk

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-play, apk, jarsigner

When I try to sign the unsign apk with the code:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

I getting the error:

> No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped.
>   Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after
>   the signer certificate's expiration date (2044-03-11) or after any
>   future revocation date.

Why it is happen?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**jarsigner** can generate signatures that include a timestamp, thus enabling systems/deployer (including Java Plug-in) to check whether the JAR file was signed while the signing certificate was still valid. In addition, APIs were added in J2SE 5.0 to allow applications to obtain the timestamp information.

[refer to this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/time-of-signing.html)

Use this for signing

```
jarsigner -tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

Thanks